# How to handle MySQL datetime using prisma

Tags: mysql, prisma

I have a MySQL database that contains a fair number of `datetime` columns. It turns out that MySQL `datetime` columns have no concept of a timezone, so it's basically up your code to assign it a timezone.

I am also using prisma for this project and it seems to want to assign those `datetime` fields the UTC timezone. This is not correct, the `datetime` field values are actually stored using another timezone.

Other mysql libraries like [this one](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) allow you specify a setting so that date fields come back from the database as strings rather than javascript `Date` objects. This lets me use libraries like `moment` or `luxon` to set the timezone to the correct one. However, I don't see a similar option for prisma.

How is this handled?